# My speakers don't work on my raspberry pi but my headphones do. Why is this?

Tags: audio, audio-playback

I am using a raspberry pi model B and I am trying to output sound using my new Logitech Stereo Speakers. I can't hear anything but my headphones do work. ***Please tell me why this happens and how I can fix it. Thank you.***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Pi's audio output jack can drive headphones/earphones but for a speaker you will need an amplifier.

http://www.raspberrypi.org/help/quick-start-guide/

```
Headphones

    Headphones or earphones with a 3.5mm jack will work with your
    Raspberry Pi.
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to connect speakers be sure they have their own amplifier and their own power source. The Raspbery Pi USB slots aren't delivering enough power to power speakers (own experience with simple USB speakers lead to the Raspberry Pi freezing up totally).